# How to add system items to button and action sheet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add system items like **`Add,Edit`** etc to my button in `UIViewcontroller`. I was able to find System item under `Attribute Inspector` for `BarButton` items but not for button and `ActionSheet`. Is there a way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I think its better to use some kind of custom ttf vector font and make button's font to your custom font and provide a title text. Try http://fontastic.me/

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari, I like system items provided like search, refresh, and stop, so I was wondering whether I can use them in button or in action sheet next to the text

Comment: the same system items are provided in some custom fonts. You can keep your button as type System and use them. http://fontastic.me/ has more than your system fonts. Check them out ince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create your own method and to **loop over subviews of temporary** **`BarButtonItem`**.

This function may help you (written in **Swift 3.0**).

```
func imageFromBarButtonItem(type: UIBarButtonSystemItem) -> UIImage {
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: type, target: nil, action: nil)            

        // You have to render it somewhere first
        // This is actually not affecting you design
        // This is rendering only so the system has it in memory
        UIToolbar().setItems([barButtonItem], animated: false)

        // Now you can loop and get the image
        let itemView = barButtonItem.value(forKey:"view") as! UIView
        for view in itemView.subviews {
            if view.isKind(of: UIButton.self){
                let button = view as! UIButton
                return button.imageView!.image!
            }
        }            
        return UIImage()
    }
```

Usage:

```
myView.image = self.imageFromBarButtonItem(type: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add)
```